# How to receive notifications from a host on the same Wifi network?

Tags: notifications, push-notifications

I would like to use my Android phone to display notifications sent by other hosts (PCs) on the same Wifi network. I'm not sure what the exact term is for that notification. Is there a non programmatic solution to this ? Ideally I'm looking for something that would be called from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an "easy solution" – but one way I could think of involves two apps:

- an [SSH Server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients#group_388) on the device (plus a corresponding client on the PC)
- [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker)

Sending a notification to your device could then work as follows:

1. write the notification text into a text file
2. by means of your SSH setup, copy that file to your Android device (have a specific directory there for "incoming notifications")
3. on the device, have setup *Tasker* to watch that directory on changes. Whenever a new file arrives, *Tasker* should

   1. read the new file
   2. use its content to create a notification
   3. delete the file

I have never set this up myself, I just know that *Tasker* has this capabilities (and remember having read of people using such a setup). For details on *Tasker*, please see our [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info).

Comment: That sounds ok. I'll see how well it works in practice.

Comment: Please don't forget to let us know the results then :)